# Обьединение двух запросов через union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
declare @agent nvarchar(100)=''
select 'Все' as name
union 
select name
from application a
Inner Join Agents ag on ag.id=a.agent_id
where ag.name Like '%' + @agent + '%'
union
select name
from deals d
Inner Join Agents ag on ag.id=d.agent_id
where ag.name Like '%' + @agent + '%'
```

Вопрос как отображать чтобы строка 'Все' была первым в списке?

Comment: А сейчас как выводит? Может тестовые данные поместить?

Comment: Если заменить `union` на `union all`, то озвученная цель будет достигнута. А вообще, если требуется какой-либо порядок вывода строк, то надо использовать `order by`, иначе ничего не гарантировано.

Comment: @Yaant а как они (union и union all) влияют на порядок вывода в данном случае?

Comment: @Zhandos можно попробовать добавить ORDER BY FIELD(`name`, 'Все') DESC, `name` ASC ..... в чем-то соглашусь с Yaant - без сортировки может быть непредсказуемый вывод..... хотя хочется тестовые данные взглянуть... ибо на простых данных у меня лично по вашему запросу всё выводится как вам нужно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `union` без `all` приводит к сортировке результатов, для исключения дубликатов. А при `union all` сортировка не производится и порядок строк не меняется.

Comment: @Yaant `UNION
All distinct rows selected by either query

UNION ALL
All rows selected by either query, including all duplicates`  ни слова про сортировку....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, но вот это самое `all distinct rows` и достигается при помощи сортировки. Чтобы далеко не ходить, сравните результаты: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно (и даже нужно) добавить принудительную нумерацию (т.к. без `order by` не стоит рассчитывать на определённый порядок вывода строк). Назначьте, к примеру, 0 для элемента 'Все', 1 для остальных.

```
declare @agent nvarchar(100)='';

;with data as (
    select 0 as orderNum, N'Все' as name
    union 
    select 1, name
    from application a
    Inner Join Agents ag on ag.id=a.agent_id
    where ag.name Like '%' + @agent + '%'
    union
    select 1, name
    from deals d
    Inner Join Agents ag on ag.id=d.agent_id
    where ag.name Like '%' + @agent + '%'
)
select name
from data
order by orderNum, name;
```

Вообще тут можно немного оптимизировать запрос, объединить application и deals и к объединению уже один раз присоединить agents с like.

```
declare @agent nvarchar(100)='';

;with agentIDs
as (
    select distinct agent_id from application
    union
    select distinct agent_id from deals
),
data as (
    select 0 as orderNum, N'Все' as name
    union all
    select 1, ag.name
    from agentIDs a
    Inner Join Agents ag on ag.id = a.agent_id
    where ag.name Like '%' + @agent + '%'
)
select name
from data
order by orderNum;
```